# Error uploading multiples images with database saves

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem when I add multiple images, they are saved in a file instead of the image being saved ...
Look
https://gyazo.com/de126b998c2967f421805e933b53b30b
My Function

```
public function createPage(Request $request)
    {

        $images = $request->input('images');

        $pages = Pages::create([
            'title'         => $request->input('title'),
            'meta_title'    => $request->input('meta_title'),
            'content'       => $request->input('content')
        ]);

        // Store each Images

        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $imagePath = Storage::disk('uploads')->put('test' .'/pages', $image);
            Files::create([
                'post_image_captation' => 'image',
                'post_image_path' => '/uploads' . $imagePath,
                'pages_id' => $pages->id
            ]);
        }

        return $pages;

    }

my blade

<div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" action="{{ route('admin.pages') }}">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Meta Title</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="meta_title" id="meta_title">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Content</label>
            <textarea class="ckeditor form-control" name="content" id="content"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="images">Imagini</label>
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="images[]" id="images">
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a solution to do what I created here in the easiest way possible?
Or is the logic good but I didn't put it into practice?

Answer (score 1):

I think you modify a bit .Instead of `Storage put` you can use `storeAs`

```
 if(isset($images)&&count((array)$images)){

     foreach ($images as $image) {
         $fileName = time().Str::random(8).'_'. $image->getClientOriginalName();
         $image->storeAs('test/pages/', $fileName, 'uploads'); 
         
    Files::create([
                   'post_image_captation' => 'image',
                    post_image_path' => '/uploads' . $fileName,
                    'pages_id' => $pages->id
           ]);
        }
}
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()I will get this

Comment: dd( $image) ; check what you get

Comment: I will get null when try to input images

Comment: then $images  is null array so you have no iamges so better check if ocndition

Comment: i have updated answer.if only  uploads if $images has